# I am trying to update dictionary by taking user input but getting error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to update dictionary by taking input from the user, pls help me in doing that.
Below is the code i am trying to implement.

```
n = int(input("enter a n value:"))

d = {}

for i in range(n):

    keys = input() # here i have taken keys as strings
    values = int(input()) # here i have taken values as integers
    d[keys] = values
print(d)

c = {}

key = input()

valu = int(input())

c[key] = valu

d.update({c})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the last line of your code. `{c}` tries to create a `set` using `c` as its element which is not allowed as `dict` object is not hashable. Change you last line to: `d.update(c)` and it should work.